# find first sequence of "/>" in regExp, javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find an img tag in a string.
I wrote for example:

```
var str ='<img border="1" height="165" id="img2" src="http://google.jpg"  />';
var regXstr = "<img (.)*/>";
var regX = new RegExp(regXstr , 'gi');
document.write(str.match(regX));
```

and the output is the whole text in `str` which is good in this case, but the if I switch the `str` with the following:

```
var str ='<img border="1" height="165" id="img2" src="http://google.jpg" /> /> />';
```

or with

```
var str ='<img border="1" height="165" id="img2" src="http://google.jpg"  /><span/>';
```

the result is still the whole text in `str`, and I want only the img tag - from  `<img` till first `/>`

Comment: [why?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/15498)

Comment: Especially, *why*, when you're working in javascript - why do you not have access to the DOM, which would allow much better focused access to elements?

Comment: [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html) is the solution

Comment: Are you not using jQuery? Don't you have access to the DOM? Oh, come on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try making the regex not-greedy using '?':

```
var regXstr = "<img (.)*?/>";
```

Comment: great. Thanks! can you explain me what the '?' is doing in this case? I know it is for marking a single character

Comment: using a '?' after a '+' or '*' tells the matcher to search for the smallest match, see http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

Comment: The second pattern will will only match the string `"<img />"` because you're missing a `.` or anything that would actually consume a character.